# Change CSS styling of a checkbox tree item in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, checkbox, treeview

I am using JavaFX 8 and have a treeView populated with checkbox tree items as shown in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFQxx.png). I want to apply CSS so that I can:

1. Change the background color of the checkbox
2. Change the border color of the checkbox
3. Change the color of the selection icons within the checkboxes

I have searched everywhere but have not been able to work out how to do this and have tried many variations of the commands below however have not been able to get it to work correctly.

```css
.tree-view .check-box-tree-cell .check-box {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-border-color: orange
}

.tree-view .check-box {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-border-color: orange
}

.check-box-tree-cell {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-border-color: orange
}

.tree-cell .check-box {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-border-color: orange;
}
```

How can I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.tree-view .check-box .box {
    -fx-background-color: lightskyblue;
    -fx-border-color: dodgerblue;
}

.tree-view .check-box:selected .box .mark,
.tree-view .check-box:indeterminate .box .mark {
    -fx-background-color: midnightblue;
}
```

This will also work if you're using [`CheckBoxTreeCell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTreeCell.html):

```css
.check-box-tree-cell > .check-box > .box {
    -fx-background-color: lightskyblue;
    -fx-border-color: dodgerblue;
}

.check-box-tree-cell > .check-box:selected > .box > .mark,
.check-box-tree-cell > .check-box:indeterminate > .box > .mark {
    -fx-background-color: midnightblue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works almost perfectly but I also had to add  ".check-box:indeterminate  .box . mark" to ensure the mark of a check-box is correctly colored when only some of a parents child nodes are selected otherwise a default white dash  appears within the parent node's box.

Comment: @rak you are right. I updated my answer to cover `indeterminate` state.